# How to detect overlapping time ranges in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE public.userlocation
(
  datetime timestamp with time zone,
  location geometry,
  locationtype integer,
  buffer double precision,
  timebuffer double precision,
  "userID" numeric,
  "ID" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"userlocation_ID_seq"'::regclass),
  "time" time with time zone
)
```

each row has a time and then a value to make a dynamic time range, in fact If `time=8` and `timebuffer=15`so time range would be `endTime= 8+15min` and `startTime= 8-15 min`.I can do this simply using this query

```
select f1.*,f1.time +(f1.timebuffer::text||' minute')::INTERVAL as startTime,f1.time-(f1.timebuffer::text||' minute')::INTERVAL as endTime
```

everything work fine, After this stage I want to query rows that their time period is between startTime and endTime in other word they overlap. I have already found this question

[PostgreSQL query to detect overlapping time ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733385/postgresql-query-to-detect-overlapping-time-ranges)

But there is a difference here,I don't have start time and endtime so I have to create them using above method. so hare is my query

```
    select f1.*,f1.time -(f1.timebuffer::text||' minute')::INTERVAL as startTime,f1.time+(f1.timebuffer::text||' minute')::INTERVAL as endTime
from userlocation f1
where exists (select f2.time -(f2.timebuffer::text||' minute')::INTERVAL as startTime,f2.time+(f2.timebuffer::text||' minute')::INTERVAL as endTime
              from userlocation f2
              where tsrange(f2.startTime, f2.endTime, '()') && tsrange(f1.startTime, f1.endTime, '()')
                and f2.locationtype = f1.locationtype
                and f2.locationtype=1
                and f2."ID" <> f1."ID");
```

But I get this error

```
[2016-08-27 23:42:45] [42703] ERROR: column f2.starttime does not exist
```

Position: 372

I think At first I should create F2 table but I dont know how,Can you please give me some hints?

Comment: the alias `as startTime` is not visible from the inner query. Push it into a subquery and join with that. (or use a CTE) ( a temp view could also work)

Comment: Why is startTime > endTime in your query? I mean the operation you are doing with adding/substracting interval.

Comment: @wildplasser sorry but I cant figure out what you mean,Can you please give me some example?thanks

Comment: @KamilG. sorry It is a mistake in type

Comment: BTW: the `f1.startTime` is also not visible; but `f2.startTime` is seen first by the parser.

Comment: @wildplasser How can I fix it?Can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First: The column-alias (`select expression AS somename`) is not usable from *within* its query, it is only visible from *outside* the query. You can solve this by wrapping it into a `(subquery) xx` or a view or a CTE
- Second: don't repeat yourself: if you need to compute the same expression(s) twice, you could be doing too much ...

---

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW omg AS
        SELECT fx.*,fx.time -(fx.timebuffer::text||' minute')::INTERVAL as startTime
        ,fx.time+(fx.timebuffer::text||' minute')::INTERVAL as endTime
        , fx.locationtype
        , fx.ID
        -- ... maybe more columns and expressions ...
        FROM userlocation fx
        ;


SELECT f1.startTime, f1.endTime
        -- ... maybe more columns and expressions ...
FROM omg f1 
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM omg f2
   WHERE tsrange(f2.startTime, f2.endTime, '()') && tsrange(f1.startTime, f1.endTime, '()')
   AND f2.locationtype = f1.locationtype
   AND f2.locationtype=1
   AND f2."ID" <> f1."ID")
        ;
```

- instead of a view you could use a CTE (the view probably performs better)
- you could probably pull the tsrange into the view or CTE, too
- I didn't check the logic

---

For completeness, the CTE version (which almost looks the same)

```
WITH omg AS (
        SELECT fx.*,fx.time -(fx.timebuffer::text||' minute')::INTERVAL as startTime
        ,fx.time+(fx.timebuffer::text||' minute')::INTERVAL as endTime
        , fx.locationtype
        , fx.ID
        -- ... maybe more columns and expressions ...
        FROM userlocation fx
        )
SELECT f1.startTime, f1.endTime
        -- ... maybe more columns and expressions ...
FROM omg f1 
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM omg f2
   WHERE tsrange(f2.startTime, f2.endTime, '()') && tsrange(f1.startTime, f1.endTime, '()')
   AND f2.locationtype = f1.locationtype
   AND f2.locationtype=1
   AND f2."ID" <> f1."ID")
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, But I get this error ERROR: column "locationtype" specified more than once what is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your tips too,they are very useful to me

Comment: You added `, locationtype` where I had put the `...` You need to prefix it with either `f1.` or `f2.` , (but they are the same anyway)

Comment: No,In fact I've just copied your query and changed fx.ID into fx."ID", I havent changed anything else

Comment: Wow..I get my mistake..As you said I have to delete colomns from ... part,But now I get this error,about casting. what I should do?function tsrange(time with time zone, time with time zone, unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: sorry,Thank you so much for your help