# PostgreSQL query to detect overlapping time ranges for INTERVAL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres which looks like below:

```
CREATE TABLE my_features
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  feature_id uuid NOT NULL,
  begin_time timestamptz NOT NULL,
  duration integer NOT NULL
)
```

For each feature_id there may be multiple rows with time ranges specified by begin_time .. (begin_time + duration). **duration** is in milliseconds. They may overlap. I'm looking for a fast way to find all feature_ids that have any overlaps.

I have referred to this - [Query Overlapping time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733385/postgresql-query-to-detect-overlapping-time-ranges) which is similar but works on a fixed time end time.

I have tried the below query but it is throwing an error.

Query:

```
select c1.*
from my_features c1
where exists (select 1
              from my_features c2
              where tsrange(c2.begin_time, c2.begin_time + '30 minutes'::INTERVAL, '[]') && tsrange(c1.begin_time, c1.begin_time + '30 minutes'::INTERVAL, '[]')
                and c2.feature_id = c1.feature_id
                and c2.id <> c1.id);
```

Error:

> ERROR:  function tsrange(timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone, unknown) does not exist
> LINE 5:               where tsrange(c2.begin_time, c2.begin_time...

I have used a default time interval here because I did not understand how to convert the time into minutes and substitute it with 'n minutes'.

Comment: duration example value - 1800000

Answer (score 2):

If you need a solution faster than `O(n²)`, then you can use [constraints on ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT) with btree_gist extension, possibly on a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_features_ranges (
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  feature_id uuid NOT NULL,
  range tstzrange NOT NULL,
  EXCLUDE USING GIST (feature_id WITH =, range WITH &&)
);
INSERT INTO my_features_ranges (id, feature_id, range)
select id, feature_id, tstzrange(begin_time, begin_time+duration*'1ms'::interval)
from my_features
on conflict do nothing;

select id from my_features except select id from my_features_ranges;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `OVERLAPS` predicate:

```
SELECT * -- DISTINCT f1.*
FROM my_features f1
JOIN my_features f2
  ON f1.feature_id = f2.feature_id
 AND f1.id <> f2.id
 AND (f1.begin_time::date, f1.begin_time::date + '30 minutes'::INTERVAL)
    OVERLAPS (f2.begin_time::date, f2.begin_time::date + '30 minutes'::INTERVAL);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=80bd80cd721a67ef9e5b91d76fb50c6c)**

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I was using `tsrange` on a column with timezone and for timestamp with timezone, there exist another function called `tstzrange`

Below worked for me:

EDIT: Added changes suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name

```
select c1.*
from my_features c1
where exists (select 1
              from my_features c2
              where tstzrange(c2.begin_time, c2.begin_time + make_interval(secs => c2.duration / 1000), '[]') && tstzrange(c1.begin_time, c1.begin_time + make_interval(secs => c1.duration / 1000), '[]')
                and c2.feature_id = c1.feature_id
                and c2.id <> c1.id);
```

However, the part of calculating interval dynamically is still pending

Comment: Something like `... ((c2.duration/1000)::text || 'seconds')::interval ...`?

Comment: Why the hardcoded duration of 30 minutes? Don't you need something like: `tstzrange(c2.begin_time, c2.begin_time + make_interval(secs => c2.duration / 1000))`

Comment: Actually it can be shortened to `(c2.duration || 'milliseconds')::interval`.

Comment: yes I didn't know how to pass milliseconds in the interval, hence use the hardcoded one

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the example that you shared won't calculate from the begin_time, right?

Comment: `tsrange(c2.begin_time, c2.begin_time + (c2.duration || 'milliseconds')::interval, '[]')`

Answer (score 0):

Or try this

```
select c1.*
from jak.my_features c1
where exists (select 1
              from jak.my_features c2
              where tsrange(c2.begin_time::date, c2.begin_time::date + '30 minutes'::INTERVAL, '[]') && tsrange(c1.begin_time::date, c1.begin_time::date + '30 minutes'::INTERVAL, '[]') and 
                c2.feature_id = c1.feature_id
                and c2.id <> c1.id);
```

Comment: but this would ignore the overlap between the time and will give me results which even have the same date, right?

Comment: test on a database with real data and write if it's okay